# input data in a lightbox with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, cakephp

A had a 40 input for number 1 to 9, and this data is stored. All works great.

Now I need to create an icon for each input on the right of each input and when I click one of them I need to open Lightbox modal window with an textarea in it. If I clicked in a previously editet icon, the data must be shown.

I tried to do that with facncybox, jqModal, jQuery-ui... but I didn´t success...

any example or info someone?

Thanks!

Comment: What's your specific question?

Comment: Personally I would get the inputs using jquery, and then load an element and pass in a dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it with jQuery-UI with a hidden textbox passing and argunment with rel attribute.